# using sed to move a string in a multi line pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

how can I use sed to change this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t foo;
    uint8_t bar;
} a_somestruct_b;
```

to

```
pre_somestruct_post = restruct.
 int8lu('foo').
 int8lu('bar')
```

I have many "somestruct" structs to convert.

Comment: Could you please let us know what is the criteria of changing them? As it is not at all clear how one could write a code without knowing the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution to get you started:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/typedef struct/{p=1;next}                                # start capturing
p && $1=="}" {
   split($2,a,"_")                                        # capture "somestruct"
                                                          # in a[2]
   printf "%s_%s_%s = restruct.\n", "pre", a[2], "post"   # possibly "pre" and "post" 
                                                          # should be "a" and "b"
                                                          # here? 
   for (j=1;j<=i;j++) printf "%s%s\n", s[j], (j<i?".":"") # print saved struct fields
   delete s; i=0; p=0                                     # reinitialize
}
p && NF==2{
   split($1, b, "_")                                      # capture type
   sub(/;/,"",$2)                                         # remove ";"
   s[++i]=sprintf("  %slu('%s')", b[1], $2)               # save struct field in 
                                                          # array s
}
```

Testing this with file input.txt:

```
$ cat input.txt
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t foo;
  uint8_t bar;
} a_atruct_b;

typedef struct {
  uint8_t foo;
  uint8_t bar;
} a_bstruct_b;

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t foo;
  uint8_t bar;
} a_cstruct_b;
```

gives:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
pre_atruct_post = restruct.
  uint8lu('foo').
  uint8lu('bar')
pre_bstruct_post = restruct.
  uint8lu('foo').
  uint8lu('bar')
pre_cstruct_post = restruct.
  uint8lu('foo').
  uint8lu('bar')
```

Same thing, as a one-liner:

```
$ awk '/typedef struct/{p=1;next} p && $1=="}" {split($2,a,"_");printf "%s_%s_%s = restruct.\n", "pre", a[2], "post";for (j=1;j<=i;j++) printf "%s%s\n", s[j], (j<i?".":"");delete s; i=0; p=0} p && NF==2 {split($1, b, "_");sub(/;/,"",$2);s[++i]=sprintf("  %slu('%s')", b[1], $2)}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat sed_script
/typedef struct/{                           # find the line with "typedef struct"
  n;n;                                      # Go to next two line
  /uint8_t/{                                # Find the line with "uint8_t"
    s/uint8_t (.*);/int8lu(\x27\1\x27)./;   # substitute the line, i.e. int8lu('foo').
    h;n;                                    # copy the pattern space to the hold space,
                                            # then go to next line
    s/uint8_t (.*);/int8lu(\x27\1\x27)/;    # substitute the line, i.e. int8lu('bar')
    H;n                                     # append the pattern space to the hold space
                                            # then go to next line
  };
  s/.*_(.*)_.*/pre_\1_post = restruct./p;   # substitute and print the line,
                                            # i.e., pre_somestruct_post = restruct.
  g;p                                       # copy the hold space to the pattern space 
                                            # and then print
}

$ sed -rn -f sed_script input
pre_somestruct_post = restruct.
    int8lu('foo').
    int8lu('bar')
```

After checked the output is what you desired, added the `-i` option for `sed` to edit the file in place.

Comment: OP is not very extensive in specifying what he wants. But I doubt `uint8` will be the only type he will encounter in his input. Of course you can change that easily in your regexes, on the other hand you're answering his exact question.

Comment: Yes, the the searched pattern can be modified anytime. I just try to offer an `sed` method to fix the problem.